# How to install a custom libarry in Jupyter notebook of GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, pipenv, gcp-notebook

I am developing a Python library and I need to make it available from GCP Notebook.

Is it possible? How?

Details:

- I use Pipenv to manage my library dependencies. Currently my library source code exists in local and in a private git repository. So it is not in PyPI.
- My code has multiple module files in nested directories.
- My library's dependencies exist in PyPI.
- Using Pipenv, the dependencies are described in Pipefile.
- This is the type of my Jupyter VM instance : https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm
- And this is some interesting structure I could find using SSH from Google console :

```
$ ls /opt/deeplearning/ 
bin  binaries  deps  jupyter  metadata  proxy-agent-config.json  restriction  src  workspace
```

- I envisage to install my library (using `pip` or something else) to be able to import its modules from the notebooks.
- I need that all the dependencies of my library to be installed when installing the library.
- If the Python Packages Index is public, I don't want to publish my library in it being proprietary.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your custom library? On PyPI? In a git repo somewhere?

Comment: In my local machine and in a proprietary (not public) git repository

Comment: Hi, could you provide more detail about your library? There multiple alternatives to installing packages on GCP, such as Terminal or in a Code cell. are you considering to enable your library to install trough pip?

Comment: Hi @YorJaggy I have done an edit to my question. thank you

Comment: How can you authenticate with your git repo? Can you use `git+ssh://` or `git+https://`?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is: you are writing your own python module, which depends on many third-part python packages (can be installed with pip).

In this situation, I would probably do a pip freeze on the actual environment where the module loads everything perfectly.

`pip freeze > requirements.txt` (It will create a requirements.txt file with all the dependency modules/libraries)

Now, once in the jupyter notebook, you can use the following command to first install all the requirements.

(Run the following in the notebook code cell)

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```